# How to safely create one-to-many tables from a table with existing records?

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have a table with 1000s of orders records, one order can have 1 or more products with it, but, all data is in single table. ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4340b0))

Instead, orders data should be in `orders` table and products in that order should be in a mapping table

Existing table of orders I have

```
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
| orders_auto_inc | order_id | product_code |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
|               1 |      333 | abcd         |
|               2 |      334 | same product |
|               3 |      334 | same product |
|               4 |      334 | same product |
|               5 |      337 | hij          |
+-----------------+----------+--------------+
```

New mapping table I want to create

```
CREATE TABLE orders_prod_map (
    orders_auto_inc int(10),
    product_code varchar(100)
);
```

I want the final tables look like this

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM orders;
+-----------------+----------+
| orders_auto_inc | order_id |
+-----------------+----------+
|               1 |      333 |
|               2 |      334 |
|               5 |      337 |
+-----------------+----------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM orders_prod_map;
+-----------------+--------------+
| orders_auto_inc | product_code |
+-----------------+--------------+
|               5 | hij          |
|               1 | abcd         |
|               2 | same product |
|               2 | same product |
|               2 | same product |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I can write a Python script to do that but is there anyway to import data to mapping table only with MySQL query?

Comment: If order id is the same, is product code always the same?

Comment: @ysth no, one order_id can have 1 or more product codes, its like 1 customer ordered more than one products

Comment: You should really have a quantity field as well so that you don't have duplicate rows e.g. `2 | same product`. Also you no longer need `product_code` in your `orders` table once you do this.

Comment: @Nick yes I dont need `product_code` in your `orders`. Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would add a `quantity` column to `orders_prod_map` to speed queries in the future (compute `COUNT(*)` once instead of every `SELECT`). You can generate the necessary data using these queries.

```
Create `orders_prod_map`:
INSERT INTO orders_prod_map
SELECT m.orders_auto_inc, COUNT(*), o.product_code
FROM orders o
JOIN (SELECT order_id, MIN(orders_auto_inc) AS orders_auto_inc
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY order_id) m ON m.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id, o.product_code
```

Delete duplicate rows from `orders`:

```
DELETE o1
FROM orders o1
JOIN orders o2 ON o2.order_id = o1.order_id
              AND o2.orders_auto_inc < o1.orders_auto_inc
```

And drop `product_code` column from `orders`:

```
ALTER TABLE orders DROP COLUMN product_code
```

Then you can `SELECT *` from each of the resultant tables (note I modified the data slightly to add a different product to order 334 to make the results more useful)

Table `orders`:

```
orders_auto_inc     order_id
1                   333
2                   334
5                   337
```

Table `orders_prod_map`:

```
orders_auto_inc     quantity    product_code
1                   1           abcd
2                   1           not same product
2                   2           same product
5                   1           hij
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QUvdygb92MCHXzQtzNJoS/0)

If you don't want a quantity column, change the `INSERT` query to:

```
INSERT INTO orders_prod_map
SELECT m.orders_auto_inc, o.product_code
FROM orders o
JOIN (SELECT order_id, MIN(orders_auto_inc) AS orders_auto_inc
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY order_id) m ON m.order_id = o.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id, product_code
```

Then the contents of `orders_prod_map` are:

```
orders_auto_inc     product_code
1                   abcd
2                   not same product
2                   same product
2                   same product
5                   hij
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QUvdygb92MCHXzQtzNJoS/1)